# C# Displays file icons in asp.net on GridView nested

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I can't to display file icons according to file extensions in asp.net GridView.

The structure of GridView is [nested](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Nested-GridView-Example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

I don't have error but the column of gridview for show icons is empty.

[image]

My code below.

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance for any help, really appreciated.

**.cs**

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string root = @FilePath;
        string folder = GridView2.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        GridView gvOrders = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gvOrders");

        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(root + "/" + folder);
        FileInfo[] fileInfo = directory.GetFiles("*.*",
        `SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvOrders.Rows)
        {

            LinkButton lnkDownload = (LinkButton)gvr.FindControl("LinkButton");
            Image ib = (Image)gvr.FindControl("ib1");
            string path = lnkDownload.Text;
            string exten = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("."));
            if (exten == ".pdf")
                ib.ImageUrl = "images/pdf.GIF";

        }            

        gvOrders.DataSource = fileInfo;
        gvOrders.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**.aspx**

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">
            <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
             CssClass="mGrid" Width="700" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Image runat="server" ID="ib1" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download" 
                         ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Justify">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" 
                                 Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' 
                                 CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FullName") %>' 
                                 runat="server"
                                OnClick="lnkDownload_Click" 
                                OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Sure ?')) return false;">
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**#Edit01**

If try with :

```
 <asp:Image runat="server" ID="ib1" ImageUrl="images/pdf.gif" />
```

In output I have :
[image]

Comment: If you just display the image outside of the grid, does it appear? I suspect the url is not resolving.

Comment: @Marisa Thank you for reply, please see **#Edit01** in my first question-

Comment: are you shure that the OnRowDataBound will be fired?

Comment: @GMSharp I'm sure because the **gvOrders** is populated from info directory and file

Comment: what happens if you put a breackpoint on  ib.ImageUrl = "images/pdf.GIF";?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess that `exten == ".pdf"` is not true.

Maybe

`if(lnkDownload.Text.EndsWith("pdf") == true)
{
   ib.ImageUrl = "images/pdf.GIF";
}`

would be better. This eliminates all that substring business.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but the column of gridview for show icons continue empty

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will help. And without the nested looping of the GridView. Note that the filename is made lower case to account for `.PDF` or `.pdf` in the filenames.

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the row back to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //get the extension from the file name
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(row["Name"].ToString().ToLower());

        //show the correct icon
        if (extension == ".pdf")
        {
            ib.ImageUrl = "/images/pdf.GIF";
        }
        else
        {
            ib.ImageUrl = "/images/unknown.GIF";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this :

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Image runat="server" ID="ImgIco"  
           ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("/images/{0}.png", 
           Eval("Name").ToString().Split(Convert.ToChar("."))
           [Eval("Name").ToString().Split(Convert.ToChar(".")).Count() - 1].ToString()) %>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```